# WPF ComboBox: Text value doesn't affect SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

If i load string value in dependency property "Text" of ComboBox. ComboBox does not pair string value with ItemsSource objects and i don't have SelectedItem filled.

Need SelectedItem for ToolTip!!

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FieldComboBox" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"                          
          Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="DataCode" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding FieldAlternative.FieldParts[0].DataItems}"
          ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=FieldComboBox}"/>
```

If i've empty Text and write, it works fine. If i've opened form with value in Text i have SelectedItem null but value Text is displayed.

Any solution how to forced pairing Text with objects in ItemsSource to fill SelectedValue, or any better solution of my problem.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value to your combobox by the SelectedItem property which will be binded to your Text Field in your ViewModel:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

So your combobox element becomes like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FieldComboBox" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"                          
          Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="DataCode" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding FieldAlternative.FieldParts[0].DataItems}"
          ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=FieldComboBox}"/>
```

Comment: It doesn|t help. SelectedItem is object DataItem and i|m using only  DataCode string from this object to fill Text property of another object (Field). So Bindint Text is to Field.Text and source of this CB is DataItems.